# SwiftUI Button Label Not Updating on State Change Within Custom View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm working on a SwiftUI app where I'm trying to dynamically generate views based on a pattern string. The pattern string contains placeholders that are replaced with SwiftUI views (e.g., Buttons). I've structured my code to have a main view (RuleInputContentView) that contains a dynamic builder (RuleInputExpressionBuilder) to parse the pattern string and insert the appropriate views.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```swift
struct RuleInputContentView: View {
    @State private var showPopover = false
    @State private var toggleButton = false
    
    var body: some View {
        RuleInputExpressionBuilder(
            pattern: String(localized: "The great toggle {{ONOFF}} and {{TOGGLE}} so let's go."),
            contents:
                RuleInputExpressionParameter(label: "ONOFF") {
                    Button("Button") {
                        showPopover.toggle()
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.link)
                    .popover(isPresented: $showPopover, content: {
                        // TODO: view to switch between on and off
                    })
                    .buttonStyle(.link)
                },
                RuleInputExpressionParameter(label: "TOGGLE") {
                    Button(action: {
                        toggleButton.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        if toggleButton {
                            Text("ON")
                        } else {
                            Text("OFF")
                        }
                    })
                    .buttonStyle(.link)
                }
        )
    }
}

// MARK: Expression Parameter

struct RuleInputExpressionParameter {
    let label: String
    let view: AnyView
    
    init<Content: View>(label: String, _ content: () -> Content) {
        self.label = label
        self.view = AnyView(content())
    }
}

// MARK: Expression Builder

struct RuleInputExpressionBuilder: View {
    enum Component {
        case text(String)
        case view(AnyView)
    }
    
    let parameters: [RuleInputExpressionParameter]
    let pattern: String
    @State private var components: [Component] = []
    
    init(pattern: String, contents: RuleInputExpressionParameter...) {
        self.pattern = pattern
        self.parameters = contents
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        /// relevant code base:
        HStack {
            buildExpression()
        }
        .onAppear {
            renderPattern()
        }
    }
    
    private func renderPattern() {
        components.removeAll()
        
        let regex = /\{\{([A-Z]+)\}\}/
        var lastEndIndex: String.Index = pattern.startIndex
        
        for match in pattern.matches(of: regex) {
            // string before tag
            var preMatchString = String(pattern[lastEndIndex..<match.0.startIndex])
            preMatchString = preMatchString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
            components.append(.text(preMatchString))
            
            // matched tag
            var matchString = String(match.output.1)
            matchString = matchString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
            // find corresponding view
            if let view = parameters.first(where: { $0.label == matchString })?.view {
                components.append(.view(view))
            }
            
            lastEndIndex = match.0.endIndex
        }
        
        // potential string after last found tag
        if lastEndIndex < pattern.endIndex {
            var postMatchString = String(pattern[lastEndIndex...])
            postMatchString = postMatchString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
            components.append(.text(postMatchString))
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private func buildExpression() -> some View {
        ForEach(Array(components.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { _, component in
            switch component {
                case .text(let string):
                    Text(string)
                case .view(let view):
                    view
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    RuleInputContentView()
        .frame(width: 300)
        .padding()
}
```

Everything works as expected except for the TOGGLE button. When pressing the TOGGLE button, I expect the label to change from "OFF" to "ON" and vice versa. However, the label doesn't update. It seems like the @State property toggleButton isn't causing the view to re-render upon change.

I've attempted to troubleshoot and ensure that @State properties are correctly implemented to trigger UI updates, but I might be missing something within the context of dynamic view generation or state management in SwiftUI.

Could anyone provide insights or solutions on how to get the TOGGLE button label to update correctly when it's pressed?

Comment: Your code shows a blank screen in my testings. I've tried it in previews and simulator.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @MatBuompy: You are right, my apologies. I have updated the code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `RuleInputExpressionBuilder`, it only render the custom view once by calling renderPattern() in onAppear block.

It causes all following UI update depends on the **private var components** which never changed after first rendering.

To quick solve its problem, I modify the code as following:

```swift
struct RuleInputContentView: View {
    @State private var showPopover = false
    @State private var toggleButton = false
    @State private var triggerFlag = false //[Modify] Manually trigger render
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RuleInputExpressionBuilder($triggerFlag,
                pattern: String(localized: "The great toggle {{ONOFF}} and {{TOGGLE}} so let's go."),
                contents:
                    RuleInputExpressionParameter(label: "ONOFF") {
                        Button("Button") {
                            showPopover.toggle()
                        }
                        .popover(isPresented: $showPopover, content: {
                            // TODO: view to switch between on and off
                        })
                    },
                RuleInputExpressionParameter(label: "TOGGLE") {
                    Button(action: {
                        toggleButton.toggle()
                        triggerFlag = true
                    }, label: {
                        Text(toggleButton ? "ON" : "OFF") // [Modify] simplify text change
                    })
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Expression Parameter

struct RuleInputExpressionParameter {
    let label: String
    let view: AnyView
    
    init<Content: View>(label: String, _ content: () -> Content) {
        self.label = label
        self.view = AnyView(content())
    }
}

// MARK: Expression Builder

struct RuleInputExpressionBuilder: View {
    enum Component {
        case text(String)
        case view(AnyView)
    }
    
    let parameters: [RuleInputExpressionParameter]
    let pattern: String
    @State private var components: [Component] = []
    @Binding private var triggerFlag : Bool // [Modify] Manually trigger rendering 

    // [Modify] add binding to setup trigger flag
    init(_ triggerFlag: Binding<Bool>, pattern: String, contents: RuleInputExpressionParameter...) {
        self._triggerFlag = triggerFlag
        self.pattern = pattern
        self.parameters = contents
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        /// relevant code base:
        HStack {
            buildExpression()
        }
        .onAppear {
            renderPattern()
        }.onChange(of: triggerFlag) { // [Modify] Listening change and force re-rendering
            if triggerFlag {
                renderPattern()
                triggerFlag = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func renderPattern() {
        debugPrint("\(#function)") //[Modify] Debug log
        components.removeAll()
        
        let regex = /\{\{([A-Z]+)\}\}/
        var lastEndIndex: String.Index = pattern.startIndex
        
        for match in pattern.matches(of: regex) {
            // string before tag
            var preMatchString = String(pattern[lastEndIndex..<match.0.startIndex])
            preMatchString = preMatchString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
            components.append(.text(preMatchString))
            
            // matched tag
            var matchString = String(match.output.1)
            matchString = matchString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
            // find corresponding view
            if let view = parameters.first(where: { $0.label == matchString })?.view {
                components.append(.view(view))
            }
            
            lastEndIndex = match.0.endIndex
        }
        
        // potential string after last found tag
        if lastEndIndex < pattern.endIndex {
            var postMatchString = String(pattern[lastEndIndex...])
            postMatchString = postMatchString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
            components.append(.text(postMatchString))
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private func buildExpression() -> some View {
        ForEach(Array(components.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { _, component in
            switch component {
                case .text(let string):
                    Text(string)
                case .view(let view):
                    view
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    RuleInputContentView()
        .frame(width: 300)
        .padding()
}
```

It should be work on Toggle, but according to the purpose of `RuleInputExpressionBuilder`, you might need to redesign your pattern to make the custom view can be bound with other values.